# Stardrive 2 : Sector Zero. Polish language translation bugs fix

Tags: stardrive

I'm looking for correct language data file: "LocKit.txt". File in the game seems to be corrupted. When I change setting in "steam_api.ini" to

```
Language=polish
```

game is unplayable. It is unplayable because:

1. Buttons do not render. Buttons have empty description.
2. ToolTips are empty.
3. Some part of game are not translated - missing keys in file data or translation not implemented in code.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Is Polish officially supported for that game? I don't see it listed on the Steam store page for _Stardrive 2: Sector Zero_.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I replace data in english column by data in polish column and remove other 4 language columns (Stay only english column with polish data). Language=english. Now game is with polish translation in 95%. Some staff are not in "LocKit.txt". This staff are controlled by Language value, so this stuff are in english (Main menu etc.). Still are some empty translations (Krazy Eddie stuffs). When I see empty translations i rollback originally "LocKit.txt" and ready info in English.

I suppose the problem is the column with russian data which is before polish data. App could not parse polish data after cyrillic signs. Perhaps tab separator could not be interpreted after cyrillic signs.

Sorry for My English.